# How to sort the list of widgets?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I would like to manage the order of the widgets, in the same way that you can manage the administration bar with the module "apostrophe-admin-bar".

I have seen that in the demo of the museum there is this option:

[image]

But looking at the code, I haven't figured out where it's done.

How can I add this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the widgets in the menu is the order in which you pass them to `apos.area`. If you're referring to putting them in columns, that is a project-level CSS override, you can find that here

CSS
https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-open-museum/blob/master/lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/public/css/utils/_admin.less#L1-L15

Area wrapper
https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-open-museum/blob/master/lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/views/pages/default.html#L27

Comment: Thank you very much, I meant to put them in columns!